# JavaFX Self-Contained Application Packaging for windows with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, javafx, inno-setup

I have a JavaFX 8 application and I am creatin an **.exe** application bundle to distribute the application to **windows** users. I am able to create an exe with **SQLite as back end** following here [JavaFX 2 Tutorial - Part 7: Deployment with e(fx)clipse](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-2-tutorial/part7/.)

Now I want to **change my whole database to MySQL** to increase performance. How can I bind MySQL with deployment package so that MySQL automatically get installed and database created in it. I have googled a lot and still i couldn't find a solution.Even in the above link,author suggested to post the question in SO.

> In the interest of completeness, I am using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45,Inno Setup 5 and Eclipse as my IDE.

Any help would me much appreciated. Thanks....

Comment: Did you see this? [Mysql install and load Database on Inno-setup. Script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19298667/850848).

Comment: No i haven't seen it before. i am not much aware of scripting. But I got the overall idea how to do it. Let me try and thanks for the quick reply. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: Please keep in mind that "installing some other software" might be in conflict regarding the licenses. Installing some MySQL-Server on a client-pc is generally not adviced, too much problems with security or restricted user-accounts (not all people have right to install such things). You might switch to HSQLDB or another embedded database instead of relying on MySQL or SQLite.

Comment: @FibreFoX Thank you. Let me look into it..